# laravel 5 Hash::check not working

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to check whether old password which user typed is matched with DB password using check hash, but its not working correctly please advice.

Below is my code which I used to update password function
fields which required are old_passwrord, new_password.

Currently it doesn't go to hash check fucntion and directly update password.

```
            else if (Hash::check('password', $getPassword->password)) 
            {
                return ['error'=>['code'=>206, 'message'=>'old password is not matching']];
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
else if (Hash::check('password', $getPassword->password))
```

with

```
else if ( ! Hash::check('password', $getPassword->password))
```

Comment: Yeah, don't bash your head too much: s*it happens

Comment: Hash::check() should return true on a successful pass. Using the `!` operator will let any incorrect password through.

Comment: @Naltroc ... which is EXACTLY what we want to assert, that the password is incorrect, and then we return an error code. What's wrong with you? You visited a question from 2015 to downvote an already correct answer?